# Oracle SQL Update invalid identifier on existing table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

i have a problem with my Oracle Sql query on the first 'where' query.
i want to change a date in the chdate column if the following is true, that in be_einheit.merge_unit_id is not null.

```
update be_container bc 
        set bc.chdate = sysdate
        where be_einheit.merge_einheit_id is not null
```

the error message is: ***"BE_EINHEIT"."MERGE_EINHEIT_ID":invalid identifier***

the problem is, that update can't use a second table except in second querys. But i have no idea how i can fix it. an exists is unfortunately not possible, because the logic of the query is then no longer correct.

Comment: What are you trying to do? A [mcve] would make things clearer.

Comment: What is `where be_einheit.merge_einheit_id ` supposed to do? As it is not a column in the table you are updating, you cannot check its value in the where clause obviously.

Comment: i have minimized the problem

Comment: @ThorstenKettner i know, but i need to check this. And i have no idea how. The customer wants it that way.

Comment: The where clause looks at one `be_container` row in order to decide whether to update it or not. So, what is `be_einheit.merge_einheit_id is not null` supposed to mean? `be_einheit` seems to be another table with possibly many rows. What have these rows to do with the `be_container` row the where clause is looking at?

Comment: On a side note: `DATE` and `SYSDATE` are misnomers in Oracle. They are datetimes really. Your column is called `chdate`. Is this a misnomer, too, and supposed to hold a date and a time? If you want the mere date, then `set bc.chdate = trunc(sysdate)`. If you want to store the complete datatime, you may want to consider renaming your column (e.g. `chdatetime`, which gives `set bc.chdatetime = sysdate`).

Comment: exactly be_einheit is a second table. 
And there is information about dates that are changed in certain periods and if they have been changed (then there is no longer a zero in it) must be updated in the other table the column chdate, so that the date should be changed to the current date.

Comment: thanks i need only the date. i edit to trunc(sysdate)

Comment: So the tables are somewhat related. How? Show the table descriptions (e.g. CREATE TABLE statements). Explain how the tables are related.

Comment: be_einheit is a table with books and many information. be_contain is a table with boxes where the books in and the information where it is located and when it was updated or relocated and when.does anyone exchange the books in the boxes , then the date of change need to update in the books table(be_einheit) and box table(be_contain)

Comment: the database is from the customer and i don't have a create statements or anything like that

Comment: There must be a column or a table relating the two tables. Is there a box id in the book table or a book id in the box table. In other words: You should know how to join the two tables.

Comment: pk-fk relationship

Comment: Edit your request. Put all the information there. What is the pk-fk relationship? What columns link the tables? This is information that should have been there from the beginning. Something like "I have two tables, books and boxes. They are 1:n related, i.e. a  book is in one box, a box can contain many books. The books.box_id is hence related to boxes.id. I want to update a book when its box ...". Don't have us guess, but always describe the task and the tables involved precisely in the request.

Comment: pk-fk = primary key foreign key

Answer (score 1):

You appear to want to use a `MERGE` statement:

```sql
MERGE INTO be_container dst
USING (
  SELECT be.einheit_id
  FROM   db2.r_be_einheit r
         INNER JOIN be_einheit be
         ON r.id = be.id
  WHERE  r.merge_einheit_id is null
  AND    be.merge_einheit_id is not null
) src
ON (dst.id = src.einheit_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE
  SET    bc.chdate = sysdate;
```

or a correlated update:

```sql
UPDATE be_container bc
SET   bc.chdate = sysdate
WHERE EXISTS(
        SELECT 1
        FROM   db2.r_be_einheit r
               INNER JOIN be_einheit be
               ON r.id = be.id
        WHERE  r.merge_einheit_id is null
        AND    be.merge_einheit_id is not null
        AND    bc.id = be.einheit_id
      );
```

Comment: i get the same error with both examples